# python-beautifulsoup same td attributes to different lists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm new to python beautiful soup and I've tried to find an answer for my question for a long time.

I try to scrape data from a website, it has many tables and td's.
There are 2 td's with the same attributes but different data usage for me.
How can I differ between them when I get all those td's?
The goal is to store them in different lists.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<td class = "xyz">
  <h4 class = "zyw">
    " 1"
   <small class = "unit">" m" </small>
  </h4>
</td>
<td class = "xyz">
  <h4 class = "zyw">
    " 8"
   <small class = "unit">" s" </small>
  </h4>
</td>
```

I manage to get the data of both with the following code:

```
for td_swellHeight in tr.find_all('td', {'class':'text-center background-gray-lighter'}):
        for h4_swellHeight in td_swellHeight.find_all('h4'):
            print(h4_swellHeight.text)
```

the output would look like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please insert html using the snippet tool via [edit] not as an image so people can copy paste to use in answers. Also, including an example of the 2 desired lists would help.

Comment: @QHarr done. Problem was solved with the help of Bushcat69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an index to skip every second td:

```
for i,td_swellHeight in enumerate(tr.find_all('td', {'class':'text-center background-gray-lighter'})):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    for h4_swellHeight in td_swellHeight.find_all('h4'):
        print(h4_swellHeight.text)
```